# Updating entity in Doctrine takes too much time

Tags: symfony, doctrine

I have the following code that updates SalesOrder Entity.

```
public function updateAction($id)
{
    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('CIInventoryBundle:SalesOrder')->find($id);
    $editForm = $this->createForm(new SalesOrderType($securityContext), $entity);
    $currentTotal = $entity->getTotal();
    $currentStatus = $entity->getStatus();

    try {
        $entity->isEditable();
    } catch (\Exception $e){
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('alert-error', $e->getMessage());
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('salesorder_show', array('id' => $entity->getId())));
    }

    $originalItems = array();
    foreach ($entity->getItems() as $item) {
        $originalItems[] = $item;
    }

    $request = $this->getRequest();
    $editForm->bindRequest($request);

    if ($editForm->isValid()) {  
        try {
            $entity->validateStatusChange($currentStatus, $currentTotal);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->get('session')->setFlash('alert-error', $e->getMessage());
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('salesorder_show', array('id' => $id)));
        }

        foreach ($entity->getItems() as $item) {
            //adjust the reserved in the inventory
            $item->adjustReserved();

            foreach ($originalItems as $key => $toDel) {
                if ($toDel->getId() === $item->getId()) {                   
                    unset($originalItems[$key]);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ($originalItems as $item) {
            $em->remove($item);
        }

        $entity->setUpdatedAt(new \DateTime('now'));
        $em->persist($entity);
        $em->flush();                   

        $this->get('session')->setFlash('alert-success', 'Record has been updated successfully!');
        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('salesorder_show', array('id' => $id)));

    } else {
        $this->get('session')->setFlash('alert-error', 'Please fill in the correct values.');
        $variantForm   = $this->createForm(new AddVariantSalesOrderType());
    }

    return array(
        'entity'      => $entity,
        'edit_form'   => $editForm->createView(),
        'variant_form' => $variantForm->createView(),
    );
}
```

When i run this code i got ""maximum execution time exceeded". I already changed the maximum execution time in php.ini to 2 minutes.

Is there anyway i can optimize my codes ?

Thanks!

Comment: it's probably not something that should be taking 2 minutes...i'd start isolating out bits and pieces so that you can get a page to run, then use the Symfony profiler to see where it's being slow.  also, change the maximum execution time to unlimited if you really think it should just take longer than 2 minutes.

Comment: Does the sql profiler show any slow queries?